# Pivot table fields in userform listbox - Excel vba

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I've being searching for a solution for this, for the past two weeks.

The purpose is to see and edit the data from the Pivot table in the userform `Listbox`.

I have a pivot table with four columns:

```
Code (number) | Name (text) | Card Number (number) | SDCard (number).
```

It's sorted by Code column.

In my userform `Listbox` I have the following code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
Dim pvtField As PivotField
Dim lngIndex As Long

Set pvtTable = Worksheets("Store").PivotTables(1)
Set pvtField = pvtTable.PivotFields("Code")

With pvtTable.PivotCache
    .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    .Refresh
End With

pvtTable.PivotFields("Code").ClearAllFilters
pvtTable.PivotFields("Code").AutoSort Order:=xlAscending, Field:="Code"

For lngIndex = 1 To pvtField.PivotItems.Count
    UserForm1.listBox1.AddItem pvtField.PivotItems(lngIndex).Name
Next

End Sub
```

I can see the field "Code" items in the `Listbox` but nothing else.

Comment: are you getting an error ? aren't all `PivotItems` of `PivotField` named "Code" appear in your `ListBox1` ?

Comment: try the code in my answer below, and let me know if that's what you meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below consists of 2 `Sub`s , one of the `Sub UserForm_Initialize` and another of `Sub ListBox1_Change`. Entire code is inside your `User_Form` Module.

(the explanation is inside the code comments)

```
Option Explicit

Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
Dim pvtField As PivotField
Dim pvtItem  As PivotItem


Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

' this code runs once hte user changes the selection of the items inside the user_form Listbox1

Dim i As Integer

' loop through all records in Listbox ans check which one is selected
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        ' if current item is selected in Listbox >> make current Pivot Items visible in Pivot table
        pvtField.PivotItems(ListBox1.List(i)).Visible = True
    Else
        ' if current item is not selected in Listbox >> hide current Pivot in Pivot table
        pvtField.PivotItems(ListBox1.List(i)).Visible = False
    End If
Next i

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

' this code runs on User_from intialize process
' it add items to the Listbox with all PivotItems in PivotField "Code"

Set pvtTable = Worksheets("Store").PivotTables(1)
Set pvtField = pvtTable.PivotFields("Code")

With pvtTable.PivotCache
    .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    .Refresh
End With

With pvtField
    .ClearAllFilters
    .AutoSort Order:=xlAscending, Field:="Code"

    ' loop through all PivotItems in PivotField "Code" and add them to ListBox1
    For Each pvtItem In .PivotItems
        UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem pvtItem.Name
    Next pvtItem
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai, Thanks for your help. Thats not the problem. With the code i post, like yours, i can see one pivot field in the listbox, but the goal is to see all the fields in the pivot table and pivot items. The pivot field 'Code' is like the índex in the table. Can you please help.

Comment: Hi, I keep trying to solve this, but with no luck. I used several other ways but get errors or only get the result of one field in the userform. I aprecciate help. thanks in advance.

Comment: @Car I would be happy to assist, I am not sure I fully understand how you want your `ListBox` to look like. Can you add more data to your post ? maybe a screen-shot of what you would like to have in your `ListBox` ? even if you make it manually with `Paint`

Comment: Hi Shai. I have the pivot table, like the image. I want to pass to passe to the listbox, the same information, with all the fields, like the structure of the pivot table. https://postimg.org/image/eeoblhew9/

Comment: @Car you want the `ListBox` to display all the data of the `PivotTable` ? 3 fields that are nested ?

Comment: Yes, thast it, and want to edit the fields (pivot items in the listbox).

Comment: Hi Shai. The 3 fields based on the values of the filter 'code'.